# Wordpress visual editor displays html

Tags: wordpress

After finishing a Wordpress site and moving it to another directory of the website, the visual editor disappeared and instead started displaying HTML and the text is white at the same time. I tried different suggestions from Wordpress support forums but nothing helped and everyone seemed to have a different answer.

Does anyone know what could have happened and how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you open console log in firefox/chrome and see if you get any 404 errors when your wp-admin tries to load resources?

Comment: It might be that the editor is actually turned off. You might be able to turn it back on or reinstall it. More on that here: http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE